# Is it possible to reference two schemas to eachother in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two Schemas, and I want to be able to access both of them from the other one.. I am trying to do something like this:

//email.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    ,Schema = mongoose.Schema
    , FoodItemSchema = require('../models/fooditem.js')
    , UserSchema = require('../models/user.js').schema
    , User = require('../models/user.js').model

    console.log(require('../models/user.js'));

    var emailSchema = new Schema({
        From : String,
        Subject : FoodItemSchema,
        Body : String,
        Date: Date,
        FoodItems : [FoodItemSchema],
        Owner : { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: "User" }
    });

    module.exports = {
        model: mongoose.model('Email', emailSchema),
        schema : emailSchema 
    }
```

//user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    ,Schema = mongoose.Schema
    , Email = require('../models/email.js').model
    , EmailSchema = require('../models/email.js').schema


console.log(require('../models/email.js'));

var userSchema = new Schema({
    googleID : String,
    accessToken : String,
    email : String,
    openId: Number,
    phoneNumber: String,
    SentEmails : [EmailSchema]
    // Logs : [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'events'}]
});
module.exports =  {
    model :  mongoose.model('User', userSchema),
    schema : userSchema
}
```

The first console.log() prints empty string and the second one prints as expected. I feel like I am trying to get the variables in the other schema even before they were created. Is there a common workaround for this? Or should I avoid double dependencies in my design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create cross-references in Mongoose. But there is no way to create cyclic dependencies in Node.js. Though, you don't need to, because there is no need to require user schema in order to create a reference:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , FoodItemSchema = require('../models/fooditem.js');

var emailSchema = new Schema({
    From: String,
    Subject: FoodItemSchema,
    Body: String,
    Date: Date,
    FoodItems: [FoodItemSchema],
    Owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'User' }
});

module.exports = {
    model: mongoose.model('Email', emailSchema),
    schema: emailSchema 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define Schema Add statements to describe common attributes:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = exports = function productCodePlugin(schema, options) {
  schema.add({productCode:{
    productCode : {type : String},
    description : {type : String},
    allowed : {type : Boolean}
  }});
};
```

then require the add statement into multiple schema definition files.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId
  , productCodePlugin = require('./productCodePlugin');

var ProductCodeSchema = new Schema({
});
ProductCodeSchema.plugin(productCodePlugin);
```